# Want to enable the htaccess password functionality on particular page in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

Here is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<LocationMatch "http://<server name>/bikes/brand/index/*">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "restricted area"
    AuthUserFile "/home/public_html/sites/labs/bikes/.htpasswds"
    require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Actually i want to enable htaccess password only for one page and page link is something like http:///bikes/homes/index/

but I don't want htaccess password on any other page.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code add it to your .htaccess and refer this [link](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/):

```
<Files "index.php">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: thanks Ashish, but i am actually using cakephp so i am not able to give file name like you gave.